# Strange (browser) caching issue in cart

Tags: magento2, cache, login

We had a third party build our initial website and I am in the process of 'fixing' things that were not done as well as we might have liked. One such issue was the manner they used to handle pages that required a user account.
The third party had just added a sign-in page as an intercessionary step before loading the product form. (there were problems with this approach in that a user could technically bookmark the form and anything after it and return to it in a non-signed in state that would cause errors)

The new method is using an open source 'blacklist' style extension where you can list specific pages that require the user to log in. This particular extension did not re-direct to the desired page so I added code to do that (using the built in setBeforeAuthUrl() and setAfterAuthUrl() session variables).

The problem we have gotten in a few, isolated tests is that some browsers appear to have some kind of cached information on the /checkout/cart/ page that again pops up the login screen when you click 'go to checkout' which will then bring you back to the user dashboard. The process will rinse-wash-repeat until you clear the browser cache or otherwise hard-reload (Ctrl-F5) the /checkout/cart/ page.

What I want to know is if there is anyway to force the user's browser to not cache anything on the /checkout/cart/ page and/or any other way to avoid whatever may be the cause of this particular page causing a login prompt to be displayed when a user is already logged in.

SW